# CSS FLEXBOX ONLY - 2 elements at top, 1 element at bottom. (not structured)

Tags: html, css, web, layout, flexbox

I have this HTML.

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div>I should be at top right</div>
  <div>I should be at top left</div>
  <div>I should be at bottom right</div>
</div>
```

I want to achieve this state:
[image]

This is my current CSS using absolute positioning

```
<style>
    .parent {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 90vh;
    }
    .parent :first-child {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    .parent :nth-child(2) {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    .parent :last-child {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
  </style>
```

However, I was told that it is possible not to use absolute positioning at all (and only use flexbox).

Any idea how I can achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Hello, could you show what you tried and what you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `flex-wrap: flex;` and adjust the width of the child elements. In your case also `flex-direction: row-reverse;` is helpful. No futher explaination added for reason of missing research efford.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.parent > div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
}


/* for styling purpose only */
.parent > div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div>I should be at top right</div>
  <div>I should be at top left</div>
  <div>I should be at bottom right</div>
</div>
```